# How to add ec2 instance user to bastion host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two instances 
1. Bastion host instance
2. Amazon linux instance.
I can login in to bastion host instance and have added key of another Amazon linux instance in which i want to allow ssh access but when i try to run command in bastion host instance it doesn't work.My security group of both ec2 instances bastion host instance and amazon linux have set inbound traffic allow to all, more over VPC and subnet are also set with proper internet gateway.

```
ssh -A ec2-user@ip
```

Can any one tell what am i missing?

Comment: "have added key of another instance": Perhaps it is just English, but if you want to connect  from bastion to another host, you should add your public key from bastion TO ( -> ) the instance. Not key OF instance (belongs to that instance) add to bastion.

I other words: connect from A to B = take the key from A, put to B, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the path to key of the instance you are trying to connect and "-i" instead of "-A" check below command.

```
ssh -i /path-to-key/key.pem ec2-user@ip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run ssh in verbose mode (-v) to see if the relevant key is getting used or if any other issue:

```
ssh -v -A ec2-user@ip
```

Also the @IP in use is instance private IP address?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use private key of the ec2 instance to login into it from the bastion host instance. You have to set the pem file to have permissions of 600. Also you can rename the key-file.pem to key-file just to avoid any unwanted attention to it. So the command would be :
`ssh -i /path_to_key-file/key-file ec2-user@ec2_instance_ip`

Comment: This seems to be a good answer. But the problem is that I don't know the path to the key file as the bastions host is restricted in any way you can think of. If you may provide some more background information to debug your suggestion?

Comment: ok, what i meant was the key file of the EC2 instance needs to be uploaded in the bastion host. The key file to login into the bastion host needs to be present on your PC. If such an arrangement is not possible, then you can use ssh tunnel feature of putty (https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/4/how-to-configure-an-ssh-tunnel-on-putty) or MobaXterm (https://blog.mobatek.net/post/ssh-tunnels-and-port-forwarding/#how-to-connect-to-remote-computers-using-a-jump-host:b8ebdf9b2cb412a3a77c16c73c0d31ed)